# Change width into 100% of Google+ Embedded Posts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I need to change the width of Google embedded posts to be responsive and viewable in modal popup windows, mobile devices, and full width websites. I've tried several ways from CSS and java script. but not worked for me.

.Yc { width: 440px;}

Follow this for your reference
https://developers.google.com/+/web/embedded-post/

[image]

Comment: Ever find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

This can be done with javascript/jquery only, because you need to style part of an iframe. So you need to apply styles to:
.Yp, .Yc, post iframe, and wrapping div. e.g.:

```
$('#___post_0', '#___post_0 iframe', '#___post_0 .Yc', '#___post_0 .Yp').css('width', '100%');
```

Of course you can use a basic class instead of id - I just used code from API example.